# OrbitControls.js - Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am starting a project in Three.js and I have correctly imported the library `OrbitControls.js`, but when I open the console to test it, I see the following error:

`Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`

And it is related to the following line code inside OrbitConstrols.js:

`THREE.OrbitControls.prototype = Object.create( THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype );`

I found similar examples that research a solution for this problem, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444592/using-threejs-orbitcontols-in-typescript), but it is made for Typescript.

Do you know a possible way to solve this issue? Or it is simply a bug of the library and even if I get an error, the object will be properly rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you are adding this in your HTML but the **order matters** when adding OrbitControls as it needs certain things from Three.js.

It should be

```
    <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

The examples are the best way to figure out what is wrong - threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html

Comment: Yep that was my problem! Thanks for your help buddy :)